# Sending value from One fragment to another

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment named AddPlayerFragment which takes some string. I am doing this like this..

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alert.setTitle("Add Player");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input
    final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            String value = input.getText().toString();

            dialog.dismiss();

            return;
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return;
                }
            });
    return alert.show();
}}
```

I want get this string value from variable value to my another Fragment named Scorecard_Fragment. I am absolute beginner in android development. Any suggestion ? I have some clue to do that via Bundle or Intent but don't know how !!

Comment: Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", value);
MyBundles.scorePLayer = value;
((Scorecard_Fragment)MainActivity.getFragment()).scorePlayer(value);

Answer (score 2):

Transfer data like this-

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("message", value);
    Scorecard_FragmentfragInfo = new Scorecard_Fragment();
    fragInfo.setArguments(bundle);
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_single, fragInfo);
    transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html.

Answer (score 0):

Easy... use sharedpreferences?

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs, 0);

alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        String value = input.getText().toString();

        prefs.edit().putString("myvalue", value).commit();

        dialog.dismiss();

        return;
    }
});
```

On your fragment you can just retrieve it then follow with your methods:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", 0);
String myPreviousValue = prefs.getString("myvalue", "");
```

Or go with Bundles with the solution posted by Amit. In my opinion SharedPreferences are better since you can easy get them in anywhere for further usages without hardcode everythings by transfering bundles to each fragment in which you'll need the value

Answer (score 0):

Create a public variable in your Scorecard_Fragment:

```
public String variable;
```

Then in AddPlayerFragment :

```
String value = input.getText().toString();
Scorecard_Fragment fragInfo = new Scorecard_Fragment();
fragInfo.variable = value;
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, fragInfo);
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem.. AddplayerFragment

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", value);
MyBundles.scorePLayer = value;
((Scorecard_Fragment) MainActivity.getFragment()).scorePlayer(value);
```

through this class

```
public class MyBundles {
public static String scorePLayer = "";
}
```