# Send data from Tablayout Fragment to other Fragment

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

I have a `ViewPager` and `Tablayout` in MainActivity , inside the `Viewpager` i have a 4 fragment where in theese fragment i load the json and populate recyclerview with data. all fragment load same structure data but with different id.

now in `Fragment_Four` I have theese codes.

> `Fragment_four.java`

```
public class Fragment_four extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<ModelDars> darsha = new ArrayList<ModelDars>();
    private RecyclerView reyclerCharDab;
    private AdapterRecyclerDars adapterRecyclerDars;
    private String after_url;

    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String poster;
    private String visitcnt;
    private String date;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_four, container, false);

        //sendjsonRequest
        sendJsonRequest();
        //recyclerview init
        reyclerCharDab = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_frg_chaharom_dab);
        reyclerCharDab.setHasFixedSize(true);
        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
        reyclerCharDab.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        reyclerCharDab.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(gridLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                loadMore();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        adapterRecyclerDars = new AdapterRecyclerDars(darsha, getActivity());
        reyclerCharDab.setAdapter(adapterRecyclerDars);
        return view;
    }


    //setJsonRequest method
    private void sendJsonRequest() {
        String firstUrl = "URL";
        darsha.clear();
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, firstUrl, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                parseJsonResponse(response);
                adapterRecyclerDars.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"khata darim" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);

    }

    //parseJsonResponse Method
    private void parseJsonResponse(JSONObject response) {
        if (response != null) {
            try {

                after_url = response.getString("pagination");

                JSONArray data = response.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject currentData = data.getJSONObject(i);
                    ModelDars newModelDars = new ModelDars();
                    id = currentData.getString("id");
                    title = currentData.getString("title");
                    poster = currentData.getString("poster");
                    visitcnt = currentData.getString("visitcnt");
                    date = currentData.getString("date");

                    newModelDars.setDars_id(id);
                    newModelDars.setDars_name(title);
                    newModelDars.setDars_img(poster);
                    newModelDars.setDars_visitcnt(visitcnt);
                    newModelDars.setDars_date(date);

                    darsha.add(newModelDars);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.d("ResponseEmpty", "Response is empty after parsing");
        }
    }

    //loadmore method triggerd when scroll
    private void loadMore() {
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, after_url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("app", after_url);
                parseJsonResponse(response);
                adapterRecyclerDars.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"khata darim" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }
}
```

In Json Response I have a {id,title,poster,visitcnt,date,cat_id,cat_name}

And This is my other fragment . this fragment exist in the `DetailActivity`

> FragmentFilm .java

```
public class FragmentFilm extends Fragment {


    public FragmentFilm() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_film, container, false);
    }

}
```

Now my question is how can send cat_id and id from json response to FragmentFilm .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending value from One fragment to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118070/sending-value-from-one-fragment-to-another)

Comment: So the fragment in Main Activity and fragment in DetailsActivity should communicate?